# Linked list with function resulting in infinite loop

Tags: c, linked-list, infinite-loop

I am trying to make a simple linked list, only with a function and two pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct leonor{
    int x;
    struct leonor * next;
}leo;
```

For purpose of practice I always look for the end of the list to add the last new node I created. The function (add) is as follows :

```
void add(leo **ad)
{
    int i;
    leo *current, *new, **previous; /*Previous points on the pointer NEXT
                                     *of an element*/

    new=malloc(sizeof(*new));

    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("x : ");
        scanf("%d",&new->x);
        new->next=NULL;

        previous = ad; /*'previous' receives adresse of head of list*/
        current = *previous;

        while(current != NULL) /*Look for last element of list*/
        {
            previous = &(current->next);
            current = current->next;
        }

        new->next = *previous;
        *previous = new;
    }
}
```

The rest of the code :

```
void display_(leo *hl)
{
    while (hl)
    {
        printf("%d -> ",hl->x);
        hl=hl->next;
    }
}
int main()
{
    leo * head;
    head = NULL;
    add(&head);
    display_(head);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is after creating linked list (list of 3 integers in here) it always contains only the number typed last. And when displaying the result is a infinite loop of the same said number. Would appreciate help.

Comment: You have too many variables to take care of. In particular: `previous = ad;` you don't need the previous variable, instead you could use (and assign to) ad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only allocating one `struct leo` and using the same one for each element you add. You need to allocate a new one for each element you put on the list.

Comment: Man It's been hours I'm compiling and compiling again! Hug thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to trying to combine your link entry information with specific data information/types. Do the link list stuff generically. Then the actual interrogation code will be easy to write. And code using your link lists to create lists will be easy.

Your link list entry structure should look like this (by the book):

```
typedef struct{
    void* prev;
    void* data;
    void* next;
}link_entry;
```

Build your code about that structure - it will make life much easier. You will need to a cast each time you want to interrogate data but it will make your code much, much easier.

```
typedef struct
{
   void* first;
   void* last;
   int n;
} LLst;
```

Some simple functions:

```
LList create()
{
   return(calloc(sizeof(LList));
}

list_entry* add_entry(LList* list, void* data)
{
   list_entry* entry = malloc(sizeof(list_entry);
   entry->prev = list->last;
   entry->data = data;
   entry->next = NULL;
   list->last=entry;
   if(!list->first) list->first=list->last;
   list->n++;
   return entry;
}

void del_entry(LList* list, list_entry* entry)
{
   /* you may wish to add a free data client procedure to free the data as     well */
   list->last=entry->prev;       
   if(entry) free(entry);
   list->n--;
   if(!list->n) list->first=list->last=NULL;
   return entry;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort.

Comment: No problem. Probably more than what you needed but might be useful for some future reference. Thanks for the question.